# two tables with a single column in common

Tags: python

I have two tables (1+2)  and am trying to merge them in table3

My two tables are:

```
Table (1)              Table (2)              Table (3)
A | B | C |            X | Y | A            X | Y | A | B | C
---------------     ---------------  ---->>  --------------- 
a1 b1 c1              x1  y1  a1              x1  y1 a1 b1 c1
a2 b1 c2              x1  y2  a1              x1  y2 a1 b1 c1
a3 b1 c2              x2  y3  a2              x2  y3 a2 b1 c2
a4 b2 c1
```

Comment: Well, go ahead...

Comment: Go ahead! What is your question here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide a [MCVE]. Also: How are your tables stored? Are you using `pandas`? How have you tried to merge them so far?

Comment: @Vignesh i think he want to append or extend the values of the table 1 and table 2 for create a third table

Comment: @SkillerDz We all understood what he want, we just think if he wants us to take time to answer his question, he may takes time to ask it first..

Comment: @MarsoSaid What's stopping you? What have you tried?

Comment: @Arount its True , first he need to take the time to Write his question and try  to create a script for try to solve his problem , if he can't he will ask his question here but by writing it

Comment: I tried to watch the following tutorial "Merge, join, and concatenate" of panda but without success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Pandas**

```
table3 = Tabl1.merge(Table2, on='A', how = 'inner')
```

Answer (score 0):

i found i way for do that using extend or append

```
table1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
table2 = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
table3 = table2.extend(table1)
```

then , i found a bug in python , the extend will be not added on table3 but it will be reversed on table2 , who you extended, that why i will do table2 = table3 , if you think it will be extend in table3 , i tryed that and it gave me:

```
>>> print table3
None
```

so that why i do that:

```
table2 = table3
```

then the resultat :

```
>>> print table3
['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3']
```